# Elementary OS PPA gives “The repository does not have a Release file.” error

Tags: command-line, ppa

I am running Ubuntu Bionic Beaver. I was trying to download the pantheon desktop environment on Ubuntu and it didn't work so I gave up. Now when I try to download themes or other things from the terminal I get an error code mentioning Elementary OS even though what I am downloading doesn't have to do with Elementary or pantheon. Here is what the terminal says:

```
jacob@jacob-MacBookPro:~$ sudo apt-add-repository ppa:tista/adapta -y
…                                          
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/elementary-os/testing/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to PPA pages ([elementary-os/testing](https://launchpad.net/~elementary-os/+archive/ubuntu/testing) and [mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily](https://launchpad.net/~mpstark/+archive/ubuntu/elementary-tweaks-daily/)) - they do not have released packages for 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver).

So you should remove these PPAs from the system with packages installed from them:

```
sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
sudo ppa-purge ppa:elementary-os/testing
sudo ppa-purge ppa:mpstark/elementary-tweaks-daily
```